# Invalid Elixir version requirement in mix.exs file

Tags: elixir, elixir-mix

I'm trying to run `mix deps.get`. When I do, I get the following error:

```
(Mix) Invalid Elixir version requirement <version> in mix.exs file
```

This is my mix.exs file:

```
def project do
    [
      app: :app,
      version: "0.1.0",
      elixir: "1.6.6",
      elixirc_paths: elixirc_paths(Mix.env()),
      compilers: [:phoenix, :gettext] ++ Mix.compilers(),
      start_permanent: Mix.env() == :prod,
      aliases: aliases(),
      deps: deps()
    ]
  end
```

which seems standard. I can't find anything on the internet about this. Changing the version doesnt work, neither does excluding the elixir  version field altogether.

NOTE:
System details:

```
Erlang/OTP 21 [erts-10.3.4] [source] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [ds:8:8:10] [async-threads:1] [hipe] [dtrace]
Mix 1.6.6 (compiled with OTP 21)
Elixir 1.6.6 (compiled with OTP 21)
```

Comment: From the language used I would assume it's your `:elixir` field, not `:version`. I tried reproducing (though not with a phoenix app), and it appears to work fine. However, you typically don't see `:elixir` locked to such a specific version. Usually you'd see something like `"~> 1.6"`. Does it work if you try that or `"~> 1.6.6"` or something?

Comment: hmm, even the fuzzy version does not work

Comment: Wild guess, but try to name application something different than `:app`. Maybe that is the problem.

Comment: Also tried this, did not work.

Comment: This is very strange, I can remove `elixir` and `version` and still `mix deps.get` works.

Comment: What happens if you remove `:elixirc_paths` and `:compilers`?

Answer (score 1):

I see this issue when Elixir is installed form old package by simply running:

```
sudo apt-get install elixir
```

Before running that however we need to add new package repository. It is described on [Elixir install page, part for Debian](https://elixir-lang.org/install.html).